# How to create global variable in Kraken JS

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I would like to be able to make a constant like

```
var BASE_URL = 'http://example.com';
```

and make it accessible in all of my kraken JS controllers. Where should I define this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `global.BASE_URL = 'http://example.com';` at the beginning of you application code.

Comment: Not that this is actually a good idea. Also, stackoverflow's guidelines require "thorough research" before posting a question. Put some more effort into the research area next time. I easily found answers to this with a simple web search.